# Angular 2 dynamic control name attr

Tags: angular, dynamic, controls

Facing issue with radio button while using tab. when i gave dynamic name it creating ng-relfect-name but not name attribute that's why my tab index not working.I need to give name attribute in order to work tab correctly.

```
<div class="col-sm-5 form-inline">
    <span *ngFor="let rv of q.responsetypevalues; let j = index " [ngSwitch]="q.responsetype">
        <label *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.questions[i].responsetypevalues[j].checked" name="model.questions[{{i}}].responsetypevalues[{{j}}].checked"> {{rv.value}}
        </label>
        <label *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="model.questions[{{i}}].answer" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="model.questions[i].answer"  [value]="rv.id"> {{rv.value}}
        </label>
        <input *ngSwitchDefault type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.questions[i].responsetypevalues[j].value" name="model.questions[{{i}}].responsetypevalues[{{j}}].value" [value]="rv.value" />
    </span>
    <div class="error">{{q.errormsg}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't find `tabindex` mentioned in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*emphasized text*i have used [attr.name] in order to add name attribute:

```
<input class="form-check-input"  type="radio" [(ngModel)]="model.questions[i].answer" name="model.questions[{{i}}].answer" [attr.name]="i" [value]="rv.id" />
```

html look like

```
<label>
<input class="form-check-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="radio"
ng-reflect-name="model.questions[4].answer" ng-reflect-value="12"
value="12" name="4"> Very Easy
</label> 
<label>
<input class="form-check-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="radio"
 ng-reflect-name="model.questions[4].answer" ng-reflect-value="13" value="13" name="4"> Easy</label> 
<label>
<input class="form-check-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="radio"
 ng-reflect-name="model.questions[8].answer" ng-reflect-value="16"
 value="16" name="8"> Very Satisfied
</label> <label>
<input class="form-check-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" type="radio"
ng-reflect-name="model.questions[8].answer" ng-reflect-value="17"
 value="17" name="8"> Satisfied
 </label>
```

now you can see name attribute, angular is not populating name attribute if you use {{}} in name, and if you do not use {{}} it will print the value as string without evaluating.that cause issue in default functionality of html radio button tab index, as it based on name attribute.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `{{}}` inside expression. Just `i` will do.

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.questions[i].responsetypevalues[j].checked" name="model.questions[i].responsetypevalues[j].checked"> {{rv.value}}
```

The `[]` around `ngModel` already tells Angular that the value is an expression.

An alternative way for binding strings is

```
src="{{imgSourceProp}}.png"
```

(no `[]` around `src`)

If you want the attribute in the DOM (Angular2 bindings by default bind to property, not attribute) use `[attr.name]="model.questions[i].answer"` or `attr.name="{{model.questions[i].answer}}"`

Comment: i have all ready tried that but problem it will generate the name as model.questions[i].responsetypevalues[j].checked and this is again causing problem.Actually my form is having multiple controls textbox , checkbox and radio/ because of radio button i am facing tabindex issue as radio button work on name attr

Comment: I don't understand the comment. What is wrong with `model.questions[i].responsetypevalues[j].checked`?

Comment: as you said i did the changes now my html look like below(please take a look on name attr ) :<label>
                    <input class="form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" name="model.questions[i].answer" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="model.questions[i].answer" ng-reflect-value="2" value="2"> No
                </label><label>
                    <input class="form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" name="model.questions[i].answer" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="model.questions[i].answer" ng-reflect-value="1" value="1"> Yes
                </label>

Comment: I see. It is added literally. You need to either add `[]` around the property name for expressions to be evaluated or to add `{{}}` around the expression. `[name]="model.questions[i].answer"` or `name="{{model.questions[i].answer}}"` (the later stringifies the result, so if you want to pass an object or array only the former `[]` will work.

Comment: if i use {{}} to print i value inside name attr get removed nly ng-reflect-name get generated please see the below html :<label>
                    <input class="form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="model.questions[1].answer" ng-reflect-value="2" value="2"> No
                </label>

Comment: If you want the attribute in the DOM (Angular2 bindings by default bind to property, not attribute) use `[attr.name]="model.questions[i].answer"` or `attr.name="{{model.questions[i].answer}}"`. I strongly suggest you check out the tutorials at http://angular.io